# How to get cpu cores utilizations in xen?

Tags: xen

I have installed `xen` as hypervisor and there are `dom0` and some paravirtualized machins as `domu` VMs on it.
I know `xentop` is used for checking the performance of system and virtual machines and I can read the output of it for measuring the virtual machine cpu utilization, But, it just gives the total usage of cpus!
**So, is there any tool or any way to get cpu usages per cores?**

Comment: At least for me it's not clear what you are asking, are you asking if there is a way to know which physical core/s the virtual cpu of your vm is using and how the usage is distributed among physical cores?

Comment: In xen the scheduler decides which virtual cpu execute on which physical cpu (there is option on pinning the vcpu to pcpu that it is not important for the question). So, I just want to measure the physical core utilization without regarding the vcpus execution on them. maybe for the answer, the vcpu execution on which pcpu and how they are pinned or distributed should be considered to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be able to get what you want from XenMon.  http://www.virtuatopia.com/index.php/Xen_Monitoring_Tools_and_Techniques

Also, try using xentop with the VCPUs option: -v or press V when inside xentop.

If you are using XenServer, then there are lots of interesting host metrics available, much more than the base Xen setup.  Check out http://support.citrix.com/servlet/KbServlet/download/38321-102-714737/XenServer-6.5.0_Administrators%20Guide.pdf, Chapter 9.

It's all particularly good if you use XenCenter to view those metrics, but then I would say that since I wrote a significant portion of it ;-)